# lyAutomation tool using vba excel and With the tool you can assign test to any number of students just by a click

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question that how to pull the questions one after the other if the student clicks on next button. 
Here I have two excel workbook and one is master workbook and the other one is for the tool designed for giving test (student will view this).

```
  Sub Button1_Click()
   Dim s(6 To 100) As String`enter code here`
   Dim stname As String
   Dim neWb As Workbook
   Dim mypath As String
   Dim u As String
   u = "_xlsx"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     For i = 6 To 100
        s(i) = Range("E" & i).Value
        stname = s(i) & "" & u
        If s(i) = "" Then
           ActiveWorkbook.Open = False
         End If   
         On Error GoTo jamun:

         mypath = Range("B1").Value & "\" & stname 
         Set neWb =Workbooks.Open("anypath\nanoo.xls")'It can be c drive or any other drive in the system
         neWb.SaveAs filename:=mypath
         neWb.Close

         Range("B" & i).Value = mypath & "_assigning..."
         Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
         Range("F" & i).Value = "Done"
         Range("B" & i).Value = mypath & "_assigned"
         Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
         Range("B" & i).Select
        'Adding hyper link to all the lines that shows the status to whom it has been assigned and to whom it is yet to assign                   
         ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection,  Address:="mypath", TextToDisplay:=Range("B" & i).Value
         Range("B" & i).Select
         Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Range("B1").Value
      Next
      MsgBox "Test assigned successfully"
   Exit Sub
   jamun:
      MsgBox "Test assigned successfully"
   End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain it with more details like snap or sample file?

Comment: You can find the list of student names from the cell E6 and in the cell B6 you can see the status of assigning the test and assigned(Progress state)

Comment: I have an excel sheet where the cell A1 has the destination address as  where to assign the test for a group of students who are sitting in the computer lab

Comment: The excel nanoo has some design so when the students click on the excel to take the test first they see the design and they click on the start button which is reside on the bottom of the design page and it also has the user form for question and answers.

Comment: Now the target i have is to pull the question from the master excel to nanoo where the nanoo excel has the room for questions (user form with labels and text boxes and combo boxes)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: In the master excel of sheet 2 I have the multiple choice questions and that has to be pulled to nanoo workbook and students will answer that questions by choosing the right answer

Comment: Sir, y no reply yet!!!

Comment: Sir, y no reply yet!!!

Comment: Hi Shree as i told you before it would be great if you upload a image or sample file, else we are not sure about your question yet.

Comment: Sir i don't know to upload in this so i just forwarded a mail and the excel sheet what you see their is the pattern. The cell E6 and onwards are the name list of the students those who are going to take the test. and remaining.. When the student opens the excel file then he first see the welcome screen and from welcome screen. On the welcome screen the start command button has link to  to question and answer